# iterate over xml with xmlstarlet and output parent and child node values

Tags: xml, bash, xmlstarlet

I have this format in multiple XML files:

```
<bad>
 <objdesc>
 <desc id="butwba10.1.wc.01" dbi="BUTWBA10.1.1.WC">
        <physdesc>adfa;sdfkjad</physdesc>
        <related objectid="bb435.1.comdes.02"/>
        <related objectid="but614r.1.penc.01"/>
        <related objectid="but611.1.wc.01"/>
        <related objectid="but612.1.wd.01"/>
        <related objectid="bb515.1.comb.12"/>
 </desc>
 <desc id="butwba10.1.wc.02" dbi="BUTWBA10.1.2.WC">
        <physdesc>alkdjfa;sfjsdf</physdesc>
        <related objectid="but621r.1.penc.01"/>
        <related objectid="bb435.1.comdes.03"/>
 </desc>
 </objdesc>
 </bad>
```

I want output that looks like this:

```
butwba10.1.wc.01 dbi="BUTWBA10.1.1.WC" related="bb435.1.comdes.02, but614r.1.penc.01, but611.1.wc.01, but612.1.wd.01, bb515.1.comb.12"

butwba10.1.wc.02 dbi="BUTWBA10.1.2.WC" related="but621r.1.penc.01, bb435.1.comdes.03"
```

I have a bash script that uses xmlstarlet to iterate over the xml files in a directory, but it dumps all the "related values" after the last desc id. It needs to associate each desc id with each set of "related" values. And it needs to include the dbi value for each id.

```
#!/bin/bash

for x in *.xml
do
    id=$(xml sel -t -v '//bad/objdesc/desc/@id' "$x")
    arr=( $(xml sel -t -v '//bad/objdesc/desc/related/@objectid' "$x") )
    cat<<EOF >> new_file
$id related="$(perl -e 'print join ",", @ARGV' "${arr[@]}")"
EOF
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

for x in *.xml; do
  count=$(xml sel -t -v 'count(//bad/objdesc/desc/@id)' "$x")
  for ((i=1; i<=count; i++)); do
    id=$(xml sel -t -v "//bad/objdesc/desc[$i]/@id" "$x")
    arr=( $(xml sel -t -v "//bad/objdesc/desc[$i]/related/@objectid" "$x") )
    cat<<EOF
$id related="$(perl -e 'print join ",", @ARGV' "${arr[@]}")"
EOF
  done
done
```

=)

It seems like this is a job for [XSLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT). But, OK, shell can handle this too...

Can you do the rest for `dbi` ? It's better to try understanding what involves here than just cut/paste.

Comment: Nice, but we have 3 call to `xmlstarlet`. It's not optimal, but it works :)

Comment: An alternative to calling perl to join is `join=$(IFS=,; echo "${arr[*]}")` -- still have to spawn a subshell though

Comment: or, in the current shell, `printf -v join "%s, " "${arr[@]}"; join=${join%, }`

Comment: The reason behind using xmlstarlet 3 times, is that the requirements was not clear enough early in another post on SO. Things was coming bit by bits =) > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27787015/associate-an-attribute-value-of-a-node-with-a-child-node/27787142#27787142

Answer (score 1):

Agree with sputnick that XSLT is the right tool. Nevertheless, a perl answer using an XML token parser. Has the advantage that it only has to process the file once instead of repeatedly invoking xmlstarlet:

```
#!perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Parser;

my (@related, @desc); # boo, global variables

sub start {
    my ($x, $elem, %attrs) = @_;
    if ($elem eq "desc") {
        @desc = @attrs{'id', 'dbi'};
        @related = ();
    }
    elsif ($elem eq "related") {
        push @related, $attrs{objectid};
    }
}

sub end {
    my ($x, $elem) = @_;
    if ($elem eq "desc") {
        printf qq{%s dbi="%s" related="%s"\n}, @desc, join(', ', @related);
    }
}

my $parser = XML::Parser->new( Handlers => {Start => \&start, End => \&end} );
$parser->parsefile($ARGV[0]);
```

in action:

```
$ perl parse.pl file 
butwba10.1.wc.01 dbi="BUTWBA10.1.1.WC" related="bb435.1.comdes.02, but614r.1.penc.01, but611.1.wc.01, but612.1.wd.01, bb515.1.comb.12"
butwba10.1.wc.02 dbi="BUTWBA10.1.2.WC" related="but621r.1.penc.01, bb435.1.comdes.03"
```

Comment: For taking time to give a proper solution +1

Answer (score 0):

```
$ xml sel -t -m bad/objdesc/desc -v "concat(@id,' dbi=',@dbi,' ')" -m related -v @objectid -i "number(count(./preceding-sibling::related))+1<number(count(./../related))" -o ", " --else -n -b file.xml

butwba10.1.wc.01 dbi=BUTWBA10.1.1.WC bb435.1.comdes.02, but614r.1.penc.01, but611.1.wc.01, but612.1.wd.01, bb515.1.comb.12
butwba10.1.wc.02 dbi=BUTWBA10.1.2.WC but621r.1.penc.01, bb435.1.comdes.03
```